# Image of a vector with a linear transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

For transformation with matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & -4\\ 
2 & -1 & 2\\ 
-3 & 1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$
relative to the basis {$u_1,u_2,u_3 $} find the image of the vector $3u_1 -u_2 +2u_3$

I'm not sure how to solve this I tried matrix multiplication
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & -4\\ 
2 & -1 & 2\\ 
-3 & 1 & 5
\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 
-1\\ 
2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-10\\ 
11\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} = -10u_1 +11u_2$$

but i'm not even certain it's in the right direction, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: ah, Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it is correct...but do you know why? The meaning of that matrix being the representation of an endomorphism (call it $\;T\;$ , say) wrt the basis $\;\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}\;$ is that $$\begin{cases}Tu_1=\color{red}0\cdot u_1+\color{red}2u_2-\color{red}3u_3\\{}\\
Tu_2=\color{red}2u_1-\color{red}1\cdot u_2+\color{red}1\cdot u_3\\{}\\
Tu_3=\color{red}{-4}u_1+\color{red}2u_2+\color{red}5u_3\end{cases}$$

So for the vector you're given:

$$T(3u_1-u_2+2u_3)=3Tu_1-Tu_2+2Tu_3=$$

$$=3(\color{red}0\cdot u_1+\color{red}2u_2-\color{red}3u_3)-(\color{red}2u_1-\color{red}1\cdot u_2+\color{red}1\cdot u_3)+2(\color{red}{-4}u_1+\color{red}2u_2+\color{red}5u_3)=$$

$$=-10u_1+11u_2+0\cdot u_3=-10u_1+11u_2$$

Of course, as you carried it on it is way easier and faster, but the above is the reason why it works.

Comment: yes I understand now, Thank you thats exactly what I was looking for